# Doubt with Relativistic Lagrangian Expression

Tags: special-relativity, energy, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, point-particles

I'm trying to learn by myself some Lagrangian mechanics, and I found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Lagrangian_mechanics#Special_relativistic_test_particle_in_an_electromagnetic_field) this relativistic Lagrangian

$$L=\frac{1}{2}mu_{\alpha}u^{\alpha}, \tag{1}$$

where $$u^\alpha=\frac{dx^{\alpha}}{d\tau}\tag{2}$$ is the [four-velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-velocity) and I don't know if $m>0$ is the rest or relativistic mass. And here is my problem. I used these Euler-Lagrange equations

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x^{\beta}}-\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}\tau}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial u^{\beta}}\right)=0, \tag{3}$$

which are in the article and I finish with this

$$\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}\tau}\left(mu_{\beta}\right)=0.\tag{4}$$

What I think it's the conservation of four-momentum, if $m$ is the rest mass. Right? But a trouble came when I calculated the energy with this formula

$$E=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{r}}\cdot\dot{r}-L\tag{5}$$

with $r$ the position vector. I did this, I don't know if it's correct

$$E=\frac{\partial L}{\partial u^{\beta}}u^{\beta}-L\tag{6}$$

$$E=mu_{\beta}u^{\beta}-\frac{1}{2}mu_{\alpha}u^{\alpha}\tag{7}$$

Now because $$u_{\beta}u^{\beta}=c^{2}\tag{8}$$ I get

$$E=mc^{2}-\frac{1}{2}mc^{2}=\frac{1}{2}mc^{2}.\tag{9}$$

This is not the relativistic energy of the particle of course, there is a missed gamma factor which can appear if $m$ is the relativistic mass. But it isn't still the energy because of the $\frac{1}{2}$ and confuse me of what is $m$.
Is something there correct? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your second question, observe that your Hamiltonian is in fact

$$\mathcal{H}=\frac{p_{\alpha}p^{\alpha}}{2m}$$

because $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}\left(x^{\alpha},p_{\alpha}\right)$ so you are not allowed to use $u_{\alpha}$. Lets test it by trying to set up Hamilton's equations

$$\begin{cases}\frac{{\rm d}p_{\alpha}}{{\rm d}\tau}=-\frac{\partial\mathcal{H}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}=0\\\frac{{\rm d}x^{\alpha}}{{\rm d}\tau}=\frac{\partial\mathcal{H}}{\partial p_{\alpha}}=\frac{p^{\alpha}}{m}\end{cases}$$

That's exactly identical to your equation using Lagrangian mechanics, so it seems like you've constructed the right Hamiltonian. Keep in mind that the Hamiltonian **is not** the total energy, it just happens to be so in some cases. The key point here is that you can't put $p_{\alpha}p^{\alpha}=m^{2}c^{2}$, because of the same reasons you didn't put $u_{\alpha}u^{\alpha}=c^{2}$ in the Lagrangian ending up with

$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}mc^{2}$$

The fact that both $\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ are constants if you substitute the intervals means that they are constants over trajectories.

**EDIT 1:** If you want your Hamiltonian to be the total energy, you should write your Lagrangian as

$$\mathcal{L}^{\prime}=-\frac{mc^{2}}{\gamma}=-mc^{2}\sqrt{1-\frac{v^{2}}{c^{2}}}$$

and use $t$ instead of $\tau$ to get

$$\boldsymbol{p}=\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}^{\prime}}{\partial\boldsymbol{v}}=\frac{m\boldsymbol{v}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^{2}}{c^{2}}}}$$
and so

$$\mathcal{H}^{\prime}=\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}^{\prime}}{\partial\boldsymbol{v}}\cdot\boldsymbol{v}-\mathcal{L}^{\prime}=\frac{mv^{2}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^{2}}{c^{2}}}}+mc^{2}\sqrt{1-\frac{v^{2}}{c^{2}}}=$$

$$=\frac{mc^{2}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^{2}}{c^{2}}}}=\gamma mc^{2}$$

**EDIT 2:** To get the Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}^{\prime}=-\frac{mc^{2}}{\gamma}$ from yours, you should look at the action

$$S\left[u_{\alpha}\right]=\int\mathcal{L}{\rm d}\tau$$

Our goal is to change variables to $\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{v},t$ instead of $x^{\alpha},u_{\alpha},\tau$. Using $\frac{{\rm d}\tau}{{\rm d}t}=\frac{1}{\gamma}$ this gives

$$S\left[\boldsymbol{x}\right]=\int\mathcal{L}\frac{{\rm d}\tau}{{\rm d}t}{\rm d}t=\int\frac{mc^{2}}{2\gamma}{\rm d}t$$
so we get our new Lagrangian to be

$$\mathcal{L}^{\prime\prime}=\frac{mc^{2}}{2\gamma}=-\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{L}^{\prime}$$

This is identical to $\mathcal{L}^{\prime}$ up to a constant, so the physics of $\mathcal{L}^{\prime}$ and $\mathcal{L}^{\prime\prime}$ is the same.

Answer (score 4):

1. OP's Lagrangian (1) is$^1$
   $$\begin{align}L~=~&\frac{m\dot{x}^2}{2}-\frac{mc^2}{2}, \cr \dot{x}^2~:=~&g_{\mu\nu}(x)~ \dot{x}^{\mu}\dot{x}^{\nu}~<~0,  \cr \dot{x}^{\mu}~:=~& \frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\tau},\end{align}\tag{A} $$
   (up to a constant term $-\frac{mc^2}{2}$, which won't change the [EL eqs.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation)). Here $m$ is the [rest/invariant mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity). The Lagrangian (A) is equal to the following Lagrangian
   $$L~=~\frac{\dot{x}^2}{2e}-\frac{e(mc)^2}{2} \tag{B} $$
   in the gauge
   $$ e~=~\frac{1}{m}, \tag{C}$$
   cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/362807/2451) Phys.SE post. Here $e=e(\tau)$ is an einbein field, and $\tau$ is a world-line parameter (not necessarily proper time).
2. The Hamiltonian that corresponds to the Lagrangian (B) is
   $$\begin{align} H~=~& \frac{e}{2}(p^2+(mc)^2), \cr p^2~:=~&g^{\mu\nu}(x)~ p_{\mu}p_{\nu}~<~0, \cr p_{\mu}~=~& \frac{1}{e}g_{\mu\nu}(x)~\dot{x}^{\nu}, \end{align}\tag{D} $$
   cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90552/2451) Phys.SE post. In the gauge (C), the Hamiltonian (D) becomes
   $$\begin{align} H~=~& \frac{1}{2m}(p^2+(mc)^2)~=~\frac{p^2}{2m}+\frac{mc^2}{2}, \cr p_{\mu}~=~& mg_{\mu\nu}(x)~\dot{x}^{\nu},\end{align} \tag{E} $$
   which is related to OP's eq. (7) up to before mentioned constant term $\frac{mc^2}{2}$.

   For the Hamiltonian formulation in various gauges, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/250911/2451) Phys.SE post.

--

$^1$ We use the Minkowski sign convention $(−,+,+,+)$.